# SSDT creating a rollback deployment script?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

we can create a SQLServer deployment script with TFS&SSDT, but is there a way to create a rollback script, so that we can roll back the deployment?
Thank's

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As SSDT (and similar products) all work by comparing the schema in the project against a live database to bring the database in sync with the model, there's not a direct way to create a rollback script. There are also considerations regarding data changed/added/removed through pre or post-deploy scripts.

That being said, there are a handful of options.

1. Take a snapshot each time you do a release. You can use that snapshot from the prior release to do another compare for rollback purposes.
2. Maintain a prior version elsewhere - perhaps do a schema compare from your production system against your local machine. You can use that to compare against production and do a rollback.
3. Generate a dacpac of the existing system prior to release (use SQLPackage or SSDT to do that). You can use that to deploy that version of the schema back to the database if something goes wrong.
4. Take a database snapshot prior to release. Best case scenario, you don't need it and can drop the snapshot. Worst case, you could use that to rollback. Of course, you need to watch out for space and IO as you'll be maintaining that original state elsewhere.
5. Run your changes through several environments to minimize the need for a rollback. Ideally if you've run this through Development, QA, and Staging/User Acceptance environments, your code and releases should be solid enough to be able to release without any issues.

You'll need to code accordingly for rolling back data changes. That could be a bit trickier as each scenario is different. You'll need to make sure that you write a script that can undo whatever changes were part of your release. If you inserted a row, you'll need a rollback script to delete it. If you updated a bunch of data, you'll either need a backup of that data or some other way to get it back.

Comment: You can also "publish" a prior version from source control.  Because you are using source control, right?

Comment: @MarkSowul: that's not the same, is it? What if i change a single column between two releases. If source control stores the complete database schema, is there an easy way to rollback to the previous version without dropping all database objects in production database? I haven't used SSDT yet, so i'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Let's say your DB (and SSDT) version 1.0 has a table with three columns: `Id INT, Name VARCHAR(10)`.  Then in 2.0, you change it to `Id BIGINT, Name VARCHAR(10), Description VARCHAR(1000)`.  SSDT will of course change the `Id` column's type, and add the `Description` column.  If you now try to republish the version 1 schema, SSDT will remove `Description`, and change `Id` back to `INT`.  An SSDT deployment says "this is what I want the database to look like", and SSDT will only do the needed changes to make the schema look that way.  A previous version is still just a different target schema.

Comment: Kind of - SSDT will attempt to do the schema changes, but in your example of ID being a BIGINT, you could encounter issues if someone took advantage of that to put in a value that's larger than an INT can handle. Rolling back is something that will need a _little_ more handling because it involves the data in your database, not just the schema. Do you really want to lose the data entered in that new column? What about that proc that fixed a critical bug? Maybe a hotfix is in order instead? It's definitely an area to plan carefully and understand why you're rolling back.

Comment: Right; I'm by no means saying this is the magic bullet to do a full safe rollback; just that it's a peer to your options (1), (2), and (3).  If you're using source control, you don't necessarily need to take SSDT snapshots or dacpacs; it's the equivalent of just republishing an older version of the SSDT project.

Comment: Incidentally, I think you can also take a *bacpac* which includes data.  That would be more like (4).  That of course doesn't handle data that was subsequently added/modified by users after deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Before making any changes to a database project I take a snapshot (a dacpac) which I can compare the modified database project against to generate a release script.  Although it's easy enough to swap the source and target to do a reverse schema compare I've discovered it won't let me generate an update script (which would be the rollback script) from the reverse comparison, presumably because the target is a database project.

To get around that problem and generate a rollback script I do the following:

1. Deploy the modified database project to my (localdb) development database;
2. Check out a previous version of the database project from source control, from before the changes were made;
3. Run a schema compare from the previous version of the database project to the (localdb) development database;
4. Use the schema compare to generate an update script.  This update script will be a rollback script.

Although it would be nice to be able to generate a rollback script more directly the four step process above takes less than five minutes.