# How to test if DACPAC can be deployed without actual deployment

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, sqlpackage

Is it possible to test a DACPAC against the DB without deploying it? sqlpackage.exe with Action=Deploy will deploy it if no errors are found and Action=Report will just generate a report with the list of changes but deployment can still fail.

Comment: It is exceptionally difficult to predict what (a particular version of) SQL Server would do (to a particular configuration at a particular point in time) when presented with a script without actually executing it; even if DACPAC deployment implemented something like that, there would be no reason to have much faith in the outcome. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18927521/4137916) discusses some options for handling potential failure, but there's no substitute for actually running the script once you've established that it *should* work.

Comment: If your DACPAC uses versioning, then it should be sufficient to check that you're indeed going from version X to X+1 to verify the script should work (disregarding runtime issues like ongoing transactions, locks etc.) Of course, this assumes that nobody makes ad-hoc changes, but you can check for those (to some extent) by verifying that a report for deploying version X (the current version) says that it would result in no action.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish) says:

> The SqlPackage.exe publish operation *incrementally updates* the schema of a target database to match the structure of a source database.

So, the success of the operation depends on current state of database to be updated. For example, the DAC package defines following table:

```sql
table MyTable (
    X int not null
);
```

while current definition of the table is

```sql
table MyTable (
    X int null
);
```

If the column `X` doesn't contain `null`s the deployment will be succeed, and it will fail otherwise. So, there are several ways to check the deployment before publishing to production.

1. Use [`Script` action](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-script?view=sql-server-ver15) to create a script that updates the schema of a target to match the schema of a source. Afterwards you could analyze the script to find out possible fails during real deployment.
2. Use test environment. You could also copy the production database using backup or [BACPAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database) file and use it as a deployment target.